# Выпадающее меню в Wordpress

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, меню

Подскажите где искать стили выпадающего дочернего меню? Необходимо изменить положение дочерних меню на странице. Тема twentysixteen.

Comment: На этом сайте http://leninpeak.net/ дочернее подменю выпадает влево надо  вправо.

Comment: В файле style.css в папке с темой

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как найти стили?

Открываем сайт, нажимаем F12. Внизу откроется окно Development tools.

Правой кнопкой на элемент меню (например, "Выше 7000м") -> Просмотреть код. В dev tools будет выделен нужный элемент: `<li id="menu-item-274" ...`. Справа кликаем на `hov:`, потом на в чекбокс `hover`. Браузер зафиксирует наведение на элементе меню, элемент в dev tools слева получит оранжевую точку и его подменю статично повиснет на экране. Теперь с подменю можно спокойно работать, оно не будет "убегать".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кликаем ниже `<li>` на `<ul class="sub-menu">`. Видим его стили справа. Понятно, что надо изменить их на

```
left: 0;
right: auto;
```

Дописываем их прямо в окне справа. Видим, что подменю поменяло своё положение.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Наводим курсор на `style.css?ver=4.9.4:3071` и видим

```
http://leninpeak.net/wp-content/themes/twentysixteen/style.css?ver=4.9.4:3071
```

Это точное указание на имя файла стилей и номер строки в нём - 3071.

Вносите туда исправления, сбрасывайте кеш, и получите искомый результат.

PS. Но все ваши исправления слетят при обновлении темы. Поэтому лучше не трогать основной style.css, а создать [дочернюю тему](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%94%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B), и добавить в её style.css следующее:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 56.875em)
.main-navigation li:hover > ul, .main-navigation li.focus > ul {
    left: 0;
    right: auto;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, за такой развернутый ответ.