# как добавить нормальный отступ сверху

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-плагины

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

используется плагин woocommerce .в чем вопрос
1)где найти эту проблему чтобы исправить?
2)как ее исправить?

.woocommerce .businesslounge-before-shop>.content_row_wrapper - сам класс от враппера. не знаю,увеличил где на 6 процентов сверху.
3)правильно ли это?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

может кто сталкивался с такой проблемой от woocomerce,страница shop

Comment: Ну это далеко не чистый woocommerce. В нем нет никаких businesslounge. Ну а так-то - почему неправильно? Увеличили отступ, и хорошо.

Comment: Как найти css код для правки https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/785019/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8E-%D0%B2-wordpress

Comment: Изменения надо вносить в дочернюю тему https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%94%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B